# Ace Editor: Add custom keywords to Markdown mode

Tags: javascript, markdown, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I want to use some custom keywords in Markdown mode that should be highlighted by Ace. For example, I need to tell Ace that it should colorize

- keywords like `TODO`,
- regexps like `/COMMENT\.+$/` or `$1` in `/^list: \[(.+)\]/`,
- the YAML header (which is not considered by Ace)

However, the file `src/mode-markdown.js` looks aweful and http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter reads too general to me. Is there a comprehensive way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking into this myself, one thing I've done is created a custom mode-mymode.js and hacked at it to add in the keywords and items I wanted to colorize. But I'm in agreement it's an awful looking file.

On the page http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter - they do offer the mode creator, but if you go way down the page.. i think what you are looking for is the subsection on **"Extending Highlighters"**

The concept of this section is that you basically "add-on" to an existing highlight rule, which should take care of what you are looking to do.